# Tag Search Not Returning Results in Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

In the Android app, when I try to search for tags on any of the sites, it shows 'No items to show..." along with the 'Failed to load data' message. I've tried a few different sites (Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Code Review, Android Enthusiasts) as well as different tags on each site. When I manually type in the tag name, it seems to be working correctly. When I click/tap on a tag name, no results are displayed. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Open the side menu and click on one of the sites (in this example I'm using Stack Overflow)

   [image]
2. Click on the "Stack Overflow - Active questions" title and click `Tags`

   [image]
3. Click on any of the tags (in this example, I'm clicking on `C#`)

   [image]
4. This is the result I'm getting:

   [image]

I'm on version 0.1.76

Comment: I also encounter this problem on 0.1.76. Further, I get the same error when I perform *any* search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I broke this.

I went ahead and unbroke it, so searching (both normal and tag searches) will start working again as of version 0.1.77 coming out around midnight UTC.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll mark as answer soon as I get the new version.

Comment: Fix works for me!