# No Messaged Displayed when Search Return No Results in Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

In the Android app, when I perform a search that returns no results, there is no longer a message informing me no results were found. Instead it is just a blank white screen. It used to display the following message: `No items to show...` (the last image in this post shows what I'm talking about: [Tag Search Not Returning Results in Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212443/222390)). To reproduce this on the app:

1. Select any of the sites from the left menu
2. Search for some random gibberish that will not return any results in the `Search Questions...` box (for example one of my searches was "ghtyvb" on SO and another on Meta "scotch" didn't return any results, although I know neither of these are practical searches)
3. Here I am used to seeing the message `No items to show...` but currently only seeing a blank white screen

I know the message displayed in a very similar scenario just the other day because I took a screenshot of it which you can see in the above linked post. Just wondering if anyone else is able to reproduce this right now? I believe having the message show when no results are returned is important because it verifies the search was completed. When I don't see a message it makes me wonder if I just hit the wrong key on my phone and closed the keyboard on accident.

I'm currently on version 0.1.78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! I had broken this in refactoring the listviews in the app. I fixed it for version 0.1.79 coming out around midnight UTC.

Here's the intense diff:

```java
--- SingleSiteQuestionsFragment.java    Mon Dec 30 15:00:09 2013 -0500
+++ SingleSiteQuestionsFragment.java    Mon Dec 30 17:29:51 2013 -0500
@@ -266,6 +266,7 @@

         @Override
         public void onHandled() {
+            super.onHandled();
             tellParentToUpdateActionBar();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Last vote goes for you, sir!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi you're welcome and as always, I'll mark it answered soon as I get the update.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi, this is happening again on 1.0.24 (reproduced the same way as the opening post).